# android setBackgroundColor in onTouch sometimes not working

Tags: android, background-color, ontouch

I have an app where I handle all the touches myself instead of using touch and gesture detection APIs, because it is a floating window and is the only way that works.

One of the things I do is change the color of the view under the finger.
OnTouch I check which view is under the finger if it is different from the previous I run:

```
myView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

It doesn't work when I go to the view next to the current and return very fast.

I have checked it with logs and the view found is correct. And I have also checked and the line where setBackgroundColor is, is executed.

So I don't know what else to do. Are any cases in which setBackgroundColor doesn't work? Is it that if onTouch takes too much time to execute doesn't finish its tasks?

Any clue of how to fix this?

**EDIT:**
It only fails when I go to the view next to the current and return fast.
I didn't add the code because I thought it was harder to read than the abstraction I did. I have cleaned it up and posted.
If you think any methods called are relevant I can add them.
**EDIT 2:**
Code that runs if ACTION is not ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_UP. Those cases are not related.

```
if ((isPortrait && isPortraitMeasured) || (!isPortrait && isLandscapeMeasured)) {
    //Log.d("algor", "Here calculate where it is");
    final int lastCol = currentColumn;
    final int lastRow = currentRow;
    findCell((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY());

    if ((lastCol == currentColumn && lastRow == currentRow)) {
        if (isPortrait && currentRow==-1 || (!isPortrait && currentColumn==-1)
                && !wasPressed && currentTable!=mainTable) {
            //is actionBar. Check if finger is over back icon, to go back

            //Code not related to the problem...
        }

    } else {

        int currentIndex = getAppsListIndex();
        if (currentIndex >= 0) {

            View nextApp;

            if (isPortrait)
                nextApp = cellsP.get(currentTable).get(currentIndex);
            else
                nextApp = cellsL.get(currentTable).get(currentIndex);
            final Object tag = nextApp.getTag();

            if (tag instanceof FolderData) {

                //Code not related to the problem...

            } else {
                Log.d("fastf", "time to change color");
                //nextApp.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                nextApp.setBackgroundColor(whiteColor);
                //nextApp.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.white));
                /*final View app = nextApp;
                app.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        app.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    }
                });*/

            }

        } else {

            //Code not related to the problem...

        }

        int lastIndex = getAppsIndexFromInts(lastRow, lastCol);
        //lastCol != -2 is because otherwise, on opening the launcher it animates
        // the last app launched
        if (lastIndex >= 0 && lastCol != -2) {
            View lastApp;
            if (isPortrait)
                lastApp = cellsP.get(currentTable).get(lastIndex);
            else
                lastApp = cellsL.get(currentTable).get(lastIndex);


            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(lastApp,
                    "backgroundColor", getResources().getColor(R.color.clear_gray),
                    getResources().getColor(R.color.white_overlay_transition));
            animator.setDuration(500);
            animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
            animator.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: getResources().getColor takes that long,  cache it

Comment: I didn't know it took long. 
I have cached it. It didn't fix it though

Comment: where do you call myView.setBackgroundColo?

Comment: Inside of an "if" in onTouch() (and I checked that the code inside the if was run). I tried doing it with view.post() but the result was the same.

Comment: inside an "if"? sorry,  it tells me nothing...  i think that you should first learn on how to express your problems since with that level of abstraction you will get no help from anyone

Comment: Updated. I did the abstraction because I thought it was easier to understand than code out of context

Comment: this code is called if event.getAction() == ? down?  move?  up?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

nextApp.setBackgroundResource(...) instead of others.

Because of your "R.color.white" is a resource.

Have a nice day.

It was an old question but, I faced same problem and resolved with this change.

Answer (score 0):

try it

> myView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.white));

Comment: Same result than with setBackgroundColor(...)

Answer (score 0):

```
  myView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bgcolor));
```

color.xml

```
 <color name="bgcolor">#ffffff</color>
```

Comment: It's the same that I have with a different resource name. How is that supposed to change anything?

Comment: you can inherit color from xml file. you can look from the my answer at the show link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640075/how-to-inherit-style-in-layout-in-android/25642037#25642037